# How to show TableViewController when location permission allowed in alert?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, core-location

**My storyboard flow is:**

`LaunchScreen` -> `LoginViewController` -> `LocationPermissionViewController` -> `TabbarController` -> `NavigationController` -> `RestaurantsTableViewController` -> `DetailViewController`.

After user logged in, when user clicked to `Allow` option in permission alert, app should be show `RestaurantsViewController` which is in tabbar controller and navigation controller. Problem is user clicked to `Allow` option in alert, navigation and tabbar is `shown` but table view is `not show`.

I tried to make tabbar `rootViewController` after permission is allowed. But as I said navigation and tab bars are okay but table view data is not showing up.

**Here is screen recording link about my problem :**
[youtube.com/watch?v=05Jumd4Bm6Q&feature=youtu.be](http://youtube.com/watch?v=05Jumd4Bm6Q&feature=youtu.be)

Table view data is loading in this function which is in `AppDelegate`.

```
private func loadBusinesses(with coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    service.request(.search(lat: coordinate.latitude, long: coordinate.longitude)) { [weak self]
        (result) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            let root = try? strongSelf.jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: response.data)
            let viewModels = root?.businesses
                .compactMap(RestaurantListViewModel.init)
                .sorted(by: { $0.distance < $1.distance })
            if let nav = strongSelf.window.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
                let restaurantListViewController = nav.topViewController as? RestaurantTableViewController {
                restaurantListViewController.viewModels = viewModels ?? []
                //When Allow option tapped in location permission alert
            } else {
            let tab = strongSelf.storyboard
                .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarController") as! UITabBarController
                let appDelegate = AppDelegate.shared
                appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tab
                let restaurantTableViewController = self!.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RestaurantTableViewController") as? RestaurantTableViewController
                tab.viewControllers = [restaurantTableViewController] as! [UIViewController]
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print ("Error: \(error)")
        } 
    }
}
```

In `else` block if I put these code block tableView is showing it is data.

```
{
strongSelf.navigationController = nav
strongSelf.window.rootViewController?.present(nav, animated: true)   {
(nav.topViewController as? RestaurantTableViewController)?.delegate = self
                    (nav.topViewController as? RestaurantTableViewController)?.viewModels = viewModels ?? []                    }
}
```

I do not get any errors. Expected result is user should see `RestaurantsTableViewController` after permission allowed button tapped.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot to describe your problem? Black screen? Just the table? Hard to diagnose properly.

Comment: Yes I upload a screen video to youtube. Link is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05Jumd4Bm6Q&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in your tableView dataSource at `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` to see if it is at least tried to populate your tableView?

Comment: I set just now but table view data source is not works fully. Code does not entire breakpoints. But, when I close app with double click to home button and swipe and open app again without run with xcode, table view controller is shown with cell data but this time navigation and tabbar controllers are not shown